# Añadir items json a un fichero que ya contiene elementos json

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, diccionarios, python3.6

llevo dos días atascada con algo y no logro sacarlo adelante. Estoy aprendiendo python con este proyecto y seguramente algunos conceptos me están fallando.

Dejo código implicado:

```
try :
  # MAKE THE OPERATION
  res = core.client.create_order(symbol=coin,side='BUY', type='MARKET', quantity=qty, timestamp=time.time());
  res['highPrice'] = core.searchHighPrice(res['fills'])       
  core.toJSON(res)

  # APPEND THE MESSAGE TO TELEGRAM VAR
  telegramMsg += "COMPRA DE " + coin + " :\n ------- Coins: " + str(qty) + " @ " + str(coinActualPrice) + "\n"

except binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException as e:
  if (e.status_code == 400): #MIN NOTIONAL
    telegramMsg += "La compra para " + coin + " es demasiado pequeña y no llega al MIN_NOTIONAL requerido\n"
    print ("La compra para " + coin + " es demasiado pequeña y no llega al MIN_NOTIONAL requerido")
```

De este código, la parte importante es el momento en que hace la operación y luego la intenta añadir al fichero json con la función toJSON que lo que pretendo es que haga lo siguiente:

- Lee el fichero daemon.json por si tiene contenido previo
- Ese posible contenido se añade a una variable de tipo diccionario llamada "dic"
- A esa variable le añado el contenido del resultado de la operación (más abajo os dejo ejemplo)
- Reescribo todo el fichero con, supuestamente, varios items en formato json y correctamente conformado

El código de la función toJSON:

```
def toJSON(data) :
    with open(path + '/files/daemon.json', 'r+') as feedjson:
        dic = json.load(feedjson)
        dic.append(data)
        json.dump(dic, feedjson, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Esta función está dándome el siguiente fallo:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "processor.py", line 67, in <module>
  core.toJSON(res)
File "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/modules/core.py", line 31, in toJSON
  dic = json.load(feedjson)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 299, in load
  parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
  return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 342, in decode
  raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 5 (char 4)
```

Y como info, os dejo el resultado de hacer un print(res) para ver qué es lo que está dejando la variable con el resultado de la operación

```
{
   "symbol":"DOGEUSDT",
   "orderId":57589829,
   "orderListId":-1,
   "clientOrderId":"RY1yczWYPdiRvU2adPtrKf",
   "transactTime":1601768844907,
   "price":"0.00000000",
   "origQty":"4539.00000000",
   "executedQty":"4539.00000000",
   "cummulativeQuoteQty":"11.78188230",
   "status":"FILLED",
   "timeInForce":"GTC",
   "type":"MARKET",
   "side":"BUY",
   "fills":[
      {
         "price":"0.00259570",
         "qty":"4539.00000000",
         "commission":"0.00031659",
         "commissionAsset":"BNB",
         "tradeId":2669072
      }
   ],
   "highPrice":"0.00259570"
}


{
   "symbol":"VETUSDT",
   "orderId":359796488,
   "orderListId":-1,
   "clientOrderId":"nvjUxpz08N1aYqbPrgAKQX",
   "transactTime":1601768845434,
   "price":"0.00000000",
   "origQty":"1001.00000000",
   "executedQty":"1001.00000000",
   "cummulativeQuoteQty":"11.77676500",
   "status":"FILLED",
   "timeInForce":"GTC",
   "type":"MARKET",
   "side":"BUY",
   "fills":[
      {
         "price":"0.01176500",
         "qty":"1001.00000000",
         "commission":"0.00031277",
         "commissionAsset":"BNB",
         "tradeId":23380067
      }
   ],
   "highPrice":"0.01176500"
}
```

Total que el objetivo al final es que por cada moneda que se haya comprado, se genere ese json con toda la info y se guarde en el fichero daemon.json, que posteriormente leerá otro robot para monitorizar esas monedas y vender cuando se cumplan ciertas condiciones.

Comment: Algo no me cuadra. Lo que lees del archivo queda en la variable `dic`, sobre la que seguidamente haces `dic.append()`. Por tanto `dic` no sería un diccionario sino una lista, no? De otro modo no puedes hacerle `.append()`. Por otro lado lo que se ve en `res` no es ni una lista ni un diccionario, sino dos diccionarios seguidos. ¿De dónde ha salido ese `res`? No es JSON válido, que sólo puede ser o bien un objeto (diccionario) o una lista (aunque puede ser una lista de diccionarios)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día Vera, ¿ es posible que el `print(res)` que muestras sean varias respuestas del método `core.searchHighPrice()` ? En principrio:

1. Cada respuesta es un objeto y para cargarlo en un json deberías tener una lista de ellos: [res, res]
2. Creo que alguna doble comilla es la que no te deja parsear el resultado por lo que yo intentaría lo siguiente dentro del método toJSON:

```
with open('./daemon.json', 'r+') as feedjson:
    es = str(res).replace("\'", "\"")
    dic = json.loads(res)
    json.dump(dic, feedjson, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```